# WireMock's Embedded Jetty Server won't .stop() during Android ApplicationTestCase

Tags: java, android, jetty, wiremock

When programmatically calling wireMockServer.stop(), the test gets stuck in this infinite shutdown loop.  As a workaround, I have made this static, but I'd like to start up the server fresh for each test.  Any ideas on how to make this work?  Below is the code for the test as well as the logs I'm seeing after wireMockServer.stop() is called and the test gets stuck in this infinite loop.

```
public class StackOverflowApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<MyApplication> {

    private WireMockServer wireMockServer;

    public StackOverflowTest() {
        super(MyApplication.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(8080);
        wireMockServer.start();
        createApplication();
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        wireMockServer.stop();
        super.tearDown();
    }
}
```

---

```
12-08 19:27:12.125 7680-7733/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout: SelectChannelEndPoint@1a478f0{/127.0.0.1:50741<->8080,Open,in,out,R,-,29481/30000,FaultInjectingHttpConnection}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1} idle timeout check, elapsed: 29481 ms, remaining: 519 ms
12-08 19:27:12.645 7680-7733/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout: SelectChannelEndPoint@1a478f0{/127.0.0.1:50741<->8080,Open,in,out,R,-,30001/30000,FaultInjectingHttpConnection}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1} idle timeout check, elapsed: 30001 ms, remaining: -1 ms
12-08 19:27:12.646 7680-7733/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout: SelectChannelEndPoint@1a478f0{/127.0.0.1:50741<->8080,Open,in,out,R,-,30002/30000,FaultInjectingHttpConnection}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1} idle timeout expired
12-08 19:27:12.646 7680-7733/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher: ignored: WriteFlusher@1d5f8c29{IDLE} java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30001/30000 ms
12-08 19:27:12.647 7680-7712/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection: FILL_INTERESTED-->IDLE FaultInjectingHttpConnection@3ff0341c[IDLE,SelectChannelEndPoint@1a478f0{/127.0.0.1:50741<->8080,Open,in,out,-,-,30003/30000,FaultInjectingHttpConnection}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1}][p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},c=HttpChannelOverHttp@18f210ee{r=5,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=}]
12-08 19:27:12.647 7680-7733/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint: Ignored idle endpoint SelectChannelEndPoint@1a478f0{/127.0.0.1:50741<->8080,Open,in,out,-,-,30003/30000,FaultInjectingHttpConnection}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1}
12-08 19:27:12.647 7680-7712/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser: close HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1}
12-08 19:27:12.648 7680-7712/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser: START --> CLOSED
12-08 19:27:12.648 7680-7712/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection: FaultInjectingHttpConnection@3ff0341c[IDLE,SelectChannelEndPoint@1a478f0{/127.0.0.1:50741<->8080,Open,in,out,-,-,1/30000,FaultInjectingHttpConnection}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1}][p=HttpParser{s=CLOSED,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},c=HttpChannelOverHttp@18f210ee{r=5,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=}] onFillInterestedFailed java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30001/30000 ms
12-08 19:27:12.648 7680-7712/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint: oshut SelectChannelEndPoint@1a478f0{/127.0.0.1:50741<->8080,Open,in,out,-,-,1/30000,FaultInjectingHttpConnection}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1}
12-08 19:27:12.649 7680-7712/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection: fillInterested FaultInjectingHttpConnection@3ff0341c[IDLE,SelectChannelEndPoint@1a478f0{/127.0.0.1:50741<->8080,Open,in,OSHUT,-,-,2/30000,FaultInjectingHttpConnection}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1}][p=HttpParser{s=CLOSED,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},c=HttpChannelOverHttp@18f210ee{r=5,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=}]
12-08 19:27:12.649 7680-7712/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection: IDLE-->FILL_INTERESTED FaultInjectingHttpConnection@3ff0341c[FILL_INTERESTED,SelectChannelEndPoint@1a478f0{/127.0.0.1:50741<->8080,Open,in,OSHUT,-,-,2/30000,FaultInjectingHttpConnection}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1}][p=HttpParser{s=CLOSED,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},c=HttpChannelOverHttp@18f210ee{r=5,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=}]
12-08 19:27:12.650 7680-7712/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint: Ignoring local interests update 1 -> 1 for SelectChannelEndPoint@1a478f0{/127.0.0.1:50741<->8080,Open,in,OSHUT,R,-,0/30000,FaultInjectingHttpConnection}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1}
12-08 19:27:42.649 7680-7733/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout: SelectChannelEndPoint@1a478f0{/127.0.0.1:50741<->8080,Open,in,OSHUT,R,-,29999/30000,FaultInjectingHttpConnection}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1} idle timeout check, elapsed: 29999 ms, remaining: 1 ms
12-08 19:27:42.651 7680-7733/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout: SelectChannelEndPoint@1a478f0{/127.0.0.1:50741<->8080,Open,in,OSHUT,R,-,30001/30000,FaultInjectingHttpConnection}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1} idle timeout check, elapsed: 30001 ms, remaining: -1 ms
12-08 19:27:42.651 7680-7733/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout: SelectChannelEndPoint@1a478f0{/127.0.0.1:50741<->8080,Open,in,OSHUT,R,-,30001/30000,FaultInjectingHttpConnection}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1} idle timeout expired
12-08 19:27:42.652 7680-7733/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher: ignored: WriteFlusher@1d5f8c29{IDLE} java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30001/30000 ms
12-08 19:27:42.652 7680-7714/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection: FILL_INTERESTED-->IDLE FaultInjectingHttpConnection@3ff0341c[IDLE,SelectChannelEndPoint@1a478f0{/127.0.0.1:50741<->8080,Open,in,OSHUT,-,-,30002/30000,FaultInjectingHttpConnection}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1}][p=HttpParser{s=CLOSED,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},c=HttpChannelOverHttp@18f210ee{r=5,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=}]
12-08 19:27:42.652 7680-7733/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint: Ignored idle endpoint SelectChannelEndPoint@1a478f0{/127.0.0.1:50741<->8080,Open,in,OSHUT,-,-,30002/30000,FaultInjectingHttpConnection}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1}
12-08 19:27:42.652 7680-7714/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser: close HttpParser{s=CLOSED,0 of -1}
12-08 19:27:42.653 7680-7714/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser: CLOSED --> CLOSED
12-08 19:27:42.653 7680-7714/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection: FaultInjectingHttpConnection@3ff0341c[IDLE,SelectChannelEndPoint@1a478f0{/127.0.0.1:50741<->8080,Open,in,OSHUT,-,-,1/30000,FaultInjectingHttpConnection}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1}][p=HttpParser{s=CLOSED,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},c=HttpChannelOverHttp@18f210ee{r=5,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=}] onFillInterestedFailed java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30001/30000 ms
12-08 19:27:42.654 7680-7714/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint: onClose SelectChannelEndPoint@1a478f0{/127.0.0.1:50741<->8080,CLOSED,in,OSHUT,-,-,2/30000,FaultInjectingHttpConnection}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1}
12-08 19:27:42.654 7680-7714/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint: close SelectChannelEndPoint@1a478f0{/127.0.0.1:50741<->8080,CLOSED,in,OSHUT,-,-,2/30000,FaultInjectingHttpConnection}{io=1,kio=1,kro=1}
12-08 19:27:42.654 7680-7714/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager: Destroyed SelectChannelEndPoint@1a478f0{/127.0.0.1:50741<->8080,CLOSED,ISHUT,OSHUT,-,-,2/30000,FaultInjectingHttpConnection}{io=1,kio=-1,kro=-1}
12-08 19:27:42.655 7680-7707/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager: Selector loop woken up from select, 0/0 selected
12-08 19:27:42.655 7680-7698/? W/art: Long monitor contention event with owner method=int libcore.io.Posix.poll(android.system.StructPollfd[], int) from Posix.java:4294967294 waiters=0 for 59.925s
12-08 19:27:42.655 7680-7698/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: stopping org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@21c47df5 keys=0 selected=0
12-08 19:27:42.655 7680-7714/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection: onClose FaultInjectingHttpConnection@3ff0341c[IDLE,SelectChannelEndPoint@1a478f0{/127.0.0.1:50741<->8080,CLOSED,ISHUT,OSHUT,-,-,3/30000,FaultInjectingHttpConnection}{io=1,kio=-1,kro=-1}][p=HttpParser{s=CLOSED,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},c=HttpChannelOverHttp@18f210ee{r=5,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=}]
12-08 19:27:42.655 7680-7707/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager: Selector loop waiting on select
12-08 19:27:42.656 7680-7698/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager: Stopping org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@21c47df5 keys=0 selected=0
12-08 19:27:42.656 7680-7714/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint: onClose SelectChannelEndPoint@1a478f0{/127.0.0.1:50741<->8080,CLOSED,ISHUT,OSHUT,-,-,4/30000,FaultInjectingHttpConnection}{io=1,kio=-1,kro=-1}
12-08 19:27:42.657 7680-7698/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager: Queued change org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector$Stop@b9ece89
12-08 19:27:42.657 7680-7707/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager: Selector loop woken up from select, 0/0 selected
12-08 19:27:42.657 7680-7707/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager: Running change org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector$Stop@b9ece89
12-08 19:27:42.658 7680-7698/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager: Stopped org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@21c47df5 keys=-1 selected=-1
12-08 19:27:42.660 7680-7698/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle: STOPPED org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@21c47df5 keys=-1 selected=-1
12-08 19:27:42.660 7680-7707/? D/org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager: Stopped Thread[qtp1052822663-321-selector-ServerConnectorManager@9d23a9b/0,5,main] on org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@21c47df5 keys=-1 selected=-1
```

Jetty Version:

```
androidTestCompile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.2.14.v20151106"
androidTestCompile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:9.2.14.v20151106"
androidTestCompile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:9.2.14.v20151106"
androidTestCompile "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:9.2.14.v20151106"
```

Answer (score 1):

Jetty appears to be attempting a graceful `stop()`, waiting for all of the active connections and requests to finish processing first, before it finalizes the `stop()`.

Your log shows many `TimeoutException` occurrences, perhaps you should look into those and make sure you are processing your HTTP exchange properly (both on the client and the server side).  Check for persistent connection modes (pay attention to the HTTP version you are using), those are the most likely cause, based on your logs.